# Maybe I have not understood the outer product of arrays

Tags: r, vector

### Toy examples

I have two simple integer vectors, say,

```
ii <- 1:3
jj <- 1:2

names(ii) <-paste0("I_",ii)
names(jj) <-paste0("J_",jj)
ii;jj

I_1 I_2 I_3   
  1   2   3   
J_1 J_2   
  1   2
```

If I execute the *default* outer product between them,
this is what I get:

```
outer(ii,jj)

    J_1 J_2
I_1   1   2
I_2   2   4
I_3   3   6
```

Giving explicitly a function, say, to concatenate the elements of the vectors, this is what I get,

```
outer(ii, jj, function(i,j) paste(i,j,sep = "-"))

    J_1   J_2  
I_1 "1-1" "1-2"
I_2 "2-1" "2-2"
I_3 "3-1" "3-2"
```

### The problem

However, when I try to go further, using ii and jj as indices to two sets of position vectors, in order to compute the distance between the vectors the idea fails, as it is shown below,

#### The two sets of vectors:

```
vi <- data.frame(x=c(3,1,0), y=c(2,1,0)) # three position vectors
vj <- data.frame(x=c(7,1), y=c(5,1))     # two position vectors
vi;vj

  x y
1 3 2
2 1 1
3 0 0
  x y
1 7 5
2 1 1
```

#### The distance function

The function to compute the distance between two points:

```
distk <- function(p,p0) { # two point distance
    sqrt(sum((p0-p)^2))
}
```

For instance, to compute the distance between point 3 of set 1, and point 1 of set 2:

```
distk(vi[3,], vj[1,])

[1] 8.602325
```

#### The error

When I try to use the outer product, following the *logic* above, to compute the distances from points in set 1 to points in set 2, I only get an error:

```
outer(ii, jj, function(i,j) distk(vi[i,], vj[j,]))
```

> Error in dim(robj) <- c(dX, dY) :    dims [product 6] does not coincide with 
>   object [1] length

#### The question

Is there something I am missing here? Or perhaps, I haven't fully understood the outer product ...

Comment: `FUN` must be vectorized. `outer` isn't really evaluating `FUN` one pair at a time, it's extending X and Y to a common length and then calling `FUN` once, and coercing the result to have the appropriate dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Following [joran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324364/joran) comment, I introduced a *vectorized* version of the distance function in terms of the previous **distk()** function, as follows,

```
distv <- function(p,p0) { # vectorized version
    p <- if (is.null(dim(p))) as.data.frame(p) else as.data.frame(t(p))
    p0 <- if (is.null(dim(p0))) as.data.frame(p0) else as.data.frame(t(p0))
    mapply(distk, p, p0)
}
```

Using this function in combination with **outer()**, I got the desired result:

```
outer(ii, jj, function(i,j) distv(vi[i,], vj[j,]))

         J_1      J_2
I_1 5.000000 2.236068
I_2 7.211103 0.000000
I_3 8.602325 1.414214
```